# This code worked so slow on version 10 but not on earlier version

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, dynamic, version-10, backslide

**Backslide introduced after 9.0.1, persisting through 11.3, fixed in 12.0.**

---

```
r := .5 - Random[];
p = Array[{8^9 {r, r}, r + .5} &, 99];
Dynamic@Graphics[
  Disk @@@ (p = {#2 #1 + {r, r} + (1 - #2) MousePosition["Graphics", #1], #2} & @@@ p),
  PlotRange -> 44
  ]
```

This code from "[One-Liner Competition 2012](https://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/mathematica-experts-live-one-liner-competition-2012/OneLinerLiveEventWinners.nb)". I used version 10.3.1 and 9.0.1.

Comment: Would you care to tell us more about your problem? What does the code do? Do you have a speed comparison?

Comment: Which version of 10 specifically? Many have noted slowdowns for a variety of functions in versions of 10, while the revision history for 10.3 claims to have resolved a number of performance "regressions."

Comment: In my case this code works fine and is fast (Win 10 Pro, Mathematica 10.3.1, i7-4940MX 3.10GHz). It reacts directly to mouse movements.

Comment: I find this code to have significant lag in both version 7.0 and 10.1 under Windows 7.  Would you describe this as actually smooth in 9.0.1?  ***Edit:*** This code actually seems to hang my Front End when I try to close the Notebook, but weirdly the "frozen" Notebook displays this Dynamic object much more smoothly!  This deserves further attention.

Comment: Has anyone tried this in version 11?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Very slow, updating in bursts in Mathematica 11.3, Intel i7 4770 3.4GHz 16Gb RAM,   Windows 7 Professional SP1 64 bits.

Comment: @rhermans Thanks.  Please consider filing a report with WRI.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In _v8.0.4_ and _v9.0.1_ the code works smoothly, but suffers from significant delay in _v11.2_.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard From what I see, the problems happens only when the `Graphics` that is updated is the same as the `Graphics` over which `MousePosition["Graphics"]` gathers the data. If you separate them, the update is smooth for me. Also, `UpdateInterval ` seems to be ignored? (See my "answer", which is just an extended comment plus Wolfram Support's reply)

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is solved in Mathematica 12 for Windows.

Answer (score 6):

<sub>This is an extended comment that constrains the problem a bit.

I reported the problem [CASE:4174000] with the following simplified example.</sub>

### Reproducing the problem

```
p = Array[{{1, 1}, #/11} &, 10];
ump[coords_, weight_] := {
     weight coords + (1 - weight) MousePosition["Graphics", coords],
     weight
    }

Labeled[
    Graphics[
      Disk @@@ p
    , PlotRange -> 9
   ]
  , "Hovering here is smooth"]

Dynamic[
  Labeled[
    Graphics[
     Disk @@@ (ump @@@ p)
   , PlotRange -> 9
  ]
 , "Hovering here is NOT smooth"], 
UpdateInterval -> 0.5]
```

[image]

<sub>Code and graphics done in *Mathemathica 11.3.0* on Win7 64</sub>

### Analysis

Each new execution modifies the coordinates in `p` using the function `ump` that uses `MousePosition`

If one hovers the mouse pointer over the first Graphics , the update of the plot is smooth (in the second), but if we hover the mouse over the second Graphics it updates irregularly.

This may suggest that only when the `Graphics` that is updated is the same as the `Graphics` over which `MousePosition["Graphics"]` gathers the data you have some conflict.

### Wolfram Support

The answer from Wolfram Support was:

> Yes, it seems that MousePosition is not behaving as expected in this
>   scenario. Furthermore, I have only been able to reproduce this in
>   Mathematica 11.3 onwards and on Windows. Other operating systems seem
>   to respond better.
>
> Based on this information, I have made the relevant report to the
>   proper development team and I have also added the information you
>   provided to it. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a relevant
>   workaround for your specific example.